# Select column based on the row value

Tags: awk

I have file like this (Tab Separated)

```
Name  Data1  Data2  Extra  A   B   C   D  
Test1   A     C       40   23  10  12  5  
Test2   B     C       20   13  3   32  5  
Test3   C     D       44   43  0   1   5  
Test4   A     D       43   2   7   0   5
```

I need add column called frequency based on this Data1 and Data2. Freq= Data2 value/ (Data2 value+ Data1 value). For example for the Test1 Freq = 12/(12+23)

It will be easy to calculate and add values like this (for the row where Data1="A" and Date2="C"

```
  awk '{print$7/($5+$7)}‘
```

But How can I select the column based on the row value ?

Expected out

```
Name  Data1  Data2  Extra  A   B   C   D  Freq
Test1   A     C       40   23  10  12  5  0.34
Test2   B     C       20   13  3   32  5  0.91
Test3   C     D       44   43  0   1   5  0.83
Test4   A     D       43   2   7   0   5  0.71
```

Comment: "But I how can Select the column based on the row value ?" ???

Comment: I mean If I can say column name == "A" based on the row value , it will be easier to call the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 {
    $(NF+1) = "Freq"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    print
    next
}
{
    d1 = $(f["Data1"])
    d2 = $(f["Data2"])
    numer = $(f[d2])
    denom = numer + $(f[d1])
    $(f["Freq"]) = sprintf( "%.02f", (denom ? numer / denom : 0) )
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name    Data1   Data2   Extra   A       B       C       D       Freq
Test1   A       C       40      23      10      12      5       0.34
Test2   B       C       20      13      3       32      5       0.91
Test3   C       D       44      43      0       1       5       0.83
Test4   A       D       43      2       7       0       5       0.71
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a copy based on the values of `Data1`:

```
gawk '{ 
   s=($2=="A"?5:0)+($2=="B"?6:0)+($2=="C"?7:0)+($2=="D"?8:0); 
   print $0,s,(s!=0?$s:"") '}   inputfile
```

With you sample input this gives:

```
Name  Data1  Data2  Extra  A   B   C   D 0
Test1   A     C       40   23  10  12  5 5 23
Test2   B     C       20   13  3   32  5 6 3
Test3   C     D       44   43  0   0   5 7 0
Test4   A     D       43   0   7   0   5 5 0
```

The value of `s` refers to the column, so `$s` gives the value for that column.

BTW: I am using `gawk`, but this should work in `awk` too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you, I have written it a bit verbose, to emphasize on what is going on:

```
$ cat freq_from_col.awk 
function indirect(val) {
        if (val == "A")
                return $col_a
        if (val == "B")
                return $col_b
        if (val == "C")
                return $col_c
        if (val == "D")
                return $col_d

        return 0
}
BEGIN {
        col_name = 1
        col_data1 = 2
        col_data2 = 3
        col_extra = 4
        col_a = 5
        col_b = 6
        col_c = 7
        col_d = 8
}
NR == 1 {
        print $0, "Freq"
        next;
}
{
        n = indirect($col_data1);
        m = indirect($col_data2);

        print $0, sprintf("%.2f", m/(n+m));
}
```

```
$ awk -f freq_from_col.awk data.txt
Name  Data1  Data2  Extra  A   B   C   D Freq
Test1   A     C       40   23  10  12  5 0.34
Test2   B     C       20   13  3   32  5 0.91
Test3   C     D       44   43  0   1   5 0.83
Test4   A     D       43   2   7   0   5 0.71
```

Comment: That would fail with a divide-by-zero error if Data1 and Data2 were both 0.